# Will a buyer be able to recover my files if I format my mac HD and sell it?

Tags: mac, data-recovery, disk-format

If I follow the standard procedure for logging out and formatting my Mac before selling it, as described in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065 - Will the buyer be able to recover my files with forensic software ? Who is liable if the buyer can recover personal files with sensitive information, given that I followed the instructions given by support ?

If the buyer is able to retrieve info with forensic tools - why do I almost have to be a computer scientist to understand how to sell my computer safely ?

Is a user friendly deep format too much to ask ?

Comment: Do you use FileVault?

Comment: No, I did not use FileVault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted procedure these days is that you already have FileVault enabled, right from the first time you use the Mac.

If you do, then the simple format & reinstall in Apple's instructions is totally adequate to prevent any recovery.

If you don't use FileVault, then there is no *proven* * method to make your data *absolutely* * irrecoverable.

Therefore, if you don't already use FileVault, enable it first across the entire drive. Wait until it finishes encrypting your data [may be days], then follow the simple format/install instructions.
This is not as *quite* * as secure as if the drive had always been encrypted, but as good as any "secure erase" procedure.
For practical purposes SSDs are *safer* * than HDs.

*words in *italics* would take 20 pages to fully explain.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if I follow the procedure described in "What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac", the buyer can get all my personal and valuable data if he just chooses to do so by pressing "Start" in a decent file recovery application ? (given that I have not used FileVault. There are no warnings about the absolute need for FileVault in the support information)

Comment: In effect, yes, but bear in mind that FileVault has been the de-facto standard for so long now that it is assumed you already have it set. 10 years ago, the instructions would have been to do a secure erase… but that proved to be *technically* * [yes I'm back to the italics again;) insecure.

Comment: Why not just use "secure erase" from Disk Utility, and skip the potentially days long FileVault encryption?

Comment: @GlenYates - Because "secure erase" has long been proven to be nowhere near as secure as people assumed it was - one reason it is no longer available in the Trash. Encrypting, on the other hand at least somewhat securely obfuscates all data before you then remove the encryption keys. Additionally, a 'full' secure erase will take a lot longer than encryption & will hammer the drive significantly more. This is a 'best guess/best speed' attempt to do a last-ditch security step. To all intents & purposes you would need a government agency to be actively chasing you for it to not be sufficient.

Comment: Maybe I am remembering wrong, because I remember that it was turned off, but if it is not possible that it was turned off and my memory is playing tricks on me that is great! I had "El Capitan", so it is quite "new".

Comment: @GlenYates - "secure erase" doesn't exist in recovery for startup volume prior to Mojave although there is a [convoluted](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/22/secure-erase-mac-ssd-drive-recovery-mode/) workaround including encrypting it anyway.  In Mojave/Catalina it seems (for non SSD)  [you can](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/dskutl14079/18.0/mac/10.14)...

Comment: Then there is the *likelyhood* of a randomly sold Mac dropping into the hands of someone who has the interest, knowledge and tools to recover said data. Unless you have highly sensitive (read: **valuable**) data on your HD the chances of someone even attempting this is slim to none. But if you don't want to play the odds, your call...

Comment: @lxo7 I wasn't talking about using recovery, I was suggesting the secure erase from disk utility as a part of reformatting the drive. And obviously not erasing your currently booted drive but perhaps temporarily installing it in an external case. Of course the quickest and easiest way to securely erase a hard drive is to just degauss it.

Comment: @GlenYates - doesn't work so well on SSDs. As we don't know what Mac or drive the OP's machine employed, this is all getting a bit … *conversational*.

Comment: However. I tried to fill an SSD drive with data. I deleted it, and tried to recover the data. All the deletted files were easily found by the recovery tool. But that was a SSD (Samsung EVO) drive handled by Ubuntu. So if I understand correctly, it is _almost_ impossible with a mac, even if I haven't encrypted it or anything ?

Comment: @SteveChambers if it's very easy to recover for example, say, my google takeout files (years of complete google history data), it is sensitive enough for someone that is curious. Photos, videos, etc, or tens of megabytes with whatsapp chat logs for example. It is typical to have those things on your disk. If Apple suppose that people are ok with that, that is a problem IMHO.

Comment: "The accepted procedure these days is that you already have FileVault enabled" That's all there is to it. Done. Safe. Secure. Irrecoverable. No encryption, no security.

Comment: "Accepted procedure" ? How can I know from reading this : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065 ?

Comment: You don't. You should have done it when you first got the Mac, not when you're getting rid of it. https://support.apple.com/HT205749 You will have been prompted to set up FileVault as part of the first run.

Comment: Yes, it should be like an alternative procedure for “non-FileVaulters”. Like a warning or something, and steps for minimizing the potential risk.

Comment: Apple can't really be held responsible for you ignoring their recommendations. The 'alternative procedure' is what I outlined above. If you object to their methods, then you need to raise it with them, not here.

Comment: But if you follow all the recommendations from that guide, before selling your computer, you will be potentially compromised.

Comment: As already mentioned, pointing that out to me, here, is not going anywhere.

Comment: Being at least conscious about it is better than nothing

Comment: You have your answer. I'm not sure what else you could want from me. I can't change Apple's policy & telling me about it repeatedly in here is getting neither of us anywhere at all.

Comment: Hehe. I was just trying to point out that your mac can be compromised if Filevault is not enabled from the start, and that there is no information about this in the guide for selling your mac, that's all. I don't need anything else from you. You gave a very good answer. I am not asking you to update their guide or something :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SSD, the a simple erase should be sufficient. It is still possible to recover the data, but more difficult and expensive than for a mechanical hard drive.

There's a balance between the amount of effort, time and expense required to retrieve data, and the value of that data itself. If you don't have industrial or governmental secrets on your disk, then the chance that the buyer has specifically bought it with the intention of recovering data that can be used for profit is slim.

Comment: So it is not sufficient to use a recovery program (which is without any effort) ?

Comment: Data recovery is very difficult on an SSD with TRIM enabled.

Comment: I just tried to recover data from my SSD disk, and the deleted files were easily found by the recovery tool. And it doesn't have to be industrial secrets in my opinion. Sensitive data is like photos, videos, diaries, transcripts, whatsapp chat logs, logs, my google takeout files with all my google account info over the years, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions of varying extremity:

- You can boot from an external drive, or set the Mac you are going to
  sell to act as a drive (hold down the "T" key while booting, and it
  boots in target mode), then use Disk Utility to erase the "drive". 
  Use the Security Options to overwrite the the actual sectors on your
  drive.  This should sufficiently obscure any resident data from most
  recovery methods;
- If it's a physical hard drive, you can use a commercial hard drive
  degausser to erase the data;
- You can replace the drive with a new one, and keep/destroy your existing one.